# Using count ifs to find Number of matching text items across multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences of a specific item of text (R) across multiple columns for 1 criteria, the second criteria is the count is only for rows which are for a specified month (say March 17).

The table which the raw data is on is over 3000 rows each of which has a non unique date within one column. On other columns (approximately 140 of them) there are the results of inspections we carry out. I'd like to count all the Rs for a given date.

A very simple version listed below:

```
A,      AA, AB, AC, AD
Feb 17  N   A   R   R
Mar 17  R   G   N   G
Apr 17  R   G   R   G
Feb 17  G   R   A   G
```

i.e in Feb 17 there were 3 Rs
    in Mar 17 there were 1 Rs
    etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how I should understand your data structure. Could you supply a screenshot or a sample file?

Comment: How do you upload a file / place a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this if your dates are formatted as text

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AA$1:$AE$3000="R")*($A$1:$A$3000="Feb 17"))
```

or this if they are formatted as actual dates

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AA$1:$AE$3000="R")*($A$1:$A$3000=DATE(2017,2,1)))
```

with the ranges being adjusted as required.

Comment: That's great thank you, is it possible to add an additional criteria? a further column say F has different sites i.e. London, Manchester etc, which I would like to be able to separate out i.e. Rs in London in Feb 17.

Comment: Yes, you can carry on adding more criteria columns in the same way ...*($F$1:$F$3000="London") etc. as long as they have the same number of rows.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help.